# Setting variables for sheets and ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make things easier on me when writing a macro for excel by storing things in variables, makes sense right? Well when i run the sub it is not happy, here is what i have:

```
Sub TransferPrices()


''*************************
''Variables
''*************************
Dim Mon As Worksheet
Dim Tue As Worksheet
Dim Wed As Worksheet
Dim Thur As Worksheet
Dim Fri As Worksheet
Dim Sat As Worksheet
Dim Prices As Range
Dim Discount As Range
Dim todayDate As Date
Dim sheetDate As Range

''Sheet Names
Set Mon = Sheets("Monday prices")
Set Tue = Sheets("Tuesday prices")
Set Wed = Sheets("Wednesday prices")
Set Thur = Sheets("Thursday price")
Set Fri = Sheets("Frday price")
Set Sat = Sheets("Saturday price")

''Prices
Set Prices = Range("E11:E487")
Set Discount = Range("G209:G356")

''Dates
todayDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Set sheetDate = Range("Sheet_Date")


''*************************
''Change dates on sheets
''*************************
Mon.sheetDate = todayDate
Tue.sheetDate = DateDiff(d, 1, todayDate)
Wed.sheetDate = DateDiff(d, 2, todayDate)
Thur.sheetDate = DateDiff(d, 3, todayDate)
Fri.sheetDate = DateDiff(d, 4, todayDate)
Sat.sheetDate = DateDiff(d, 5, todayDate)



''*************************
''Transfer prices from Saturday sheet to Monday sheet
''*************************
Sat.Prices.Copy Mon.Prices
Sat.Discount.Copy Mon.Discount




''*************************
''Clear other sheets
''*************************
```

End Sub

When i compile the module on this line `Mon.sheetDate = todayDate` i get an error, Compile error: Method or data member not found on sheetDate. Can you not use `Mon.SheetDate` instead of `Mon.Range()` or am i missing something?

Comment: `Mon` is a Worksheet. Worksheet don't have a property nor a method called sheetDate. sheetDate is a Range of the current ActiveSheet.

Comment: You will have to use `Mon.Range("Sheet_Date") = ...`

Comment: doh, i was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: When you set a range the parent sheet is set with it. `Set sheetDate = Range("Sheet_Date")` sets the range and sheet, the sheet being the active sheet.  so `Mon.sheetDate = todayDate` is like `worksheets().worksheets().Range()`

Comment: Doing the `Mon.Range("Sheet_Date") ` will not help. You can't have the same range name on the other sheets

Comment: @Sam yes you can, if you specify the worksheet scope instead of the workbook one.

Answer (score 0):

A named range "Sheet_Date" can be defined several times:

- once per workbook (scope: workbook)
- and once per each worksheet (scope: datasheet) additionally

The worksheet-scoped name can be in the same sheet as one of the sheet-scoped names.

---

You can address each of them by e. g.

```
Set sheetDate = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Sheet_Date").RefersToRange
Set sheetDate = Sheets("Monday prices").Range("Sheet_Date")
Set sheetDate = Sheets("Tuesday prices").Range("Sheet_Date")
```

---

If you didn't set them manually before (mind the scope!), you can add names like this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Sheet_Date", _
    RefersTo:=ActiveSheet.Range("B4")
Sheets("Monday prices").Names.Add Name:="Sheet_Date", _
    RefersTo:=Sheets("Monday prices").Range("B2")
Sheets("Tuesday prices").Names.Add Name:="Sheet_Date", _
    RefersTo:=Sheets("Tuesday prices").Range("B2")
```

If they have the same name like in this example, you have to add the workbook-scoped name first - otherwise it overwrites an existing sheet-scoped name in the same sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class module, you can do roughly what you tried in your question. Do like this:
Create a Class Module and name it *DaySheet*. That is an arbitrary name which you set in the properties (press F4 to get there), but it must match the declarations in your code.
Put this code in the class module:

```
Dim m_Worksheet As Worksheet

Property Set DaySheet(DaySheet As Worksheet)
    Set m_Worksheet = DaySheet
End Property

Property Get DaySheet() As Worksheet
    Set DaySheet = m_Worksheet
End Property

Property Let SheetDate(SheetDate As Date)
    m_Worksheet.Range("A1") = SheetDate
End Property

Property Get SheetDate() As Date
    SheetDate = m_Worksheet.Range("A1").Value
End Property

Property Get Prices() As Range
    Set Prices = m_Worksheet.Range("E11:E487")
End Property

Property Get Discount() As Range
    Set Prices = m_Worksheet.Range("G209:G356")
End Property
```

Then you can use it like this in you normal module:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim TodayDate As Date


    Dim Mon As New DaySheet
    Dim Tue As New DaySheet
    Dim Wed As New DaySheet


    Set Mon.DaySheet = Worksheets("Mon")
    Set Tue.DaySheet = Worksheets("Tue")
    Set Wed.DaySheet = Worksheets("Wed")

    TodayDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    Mon.SheetDate = TodayDate
    Tue.SheetDate = TodayDate + 1
    Wed.SheetDate = TodayDate + 2

    Tue.Prices.Copy Mon.Prices

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your input. What I learned is that you cannot do Mon.VARIABLE, it has to be something other than a variable. Also in my original code i was using the DateAdd syntax in a DateDiff function, so i fixed that.

The original thought was that this was going to be more complicated then I thought, but it wasn't. I probably could have tossed some loops in there to write less code, but i don't think it needed all that. Rather than make it complicated with classes i just made it dumb.

It works how I wanted so here is the final macro:

```
Sub TransferPrices()


''*************************
''Variables
''*************************
Dim Mon As Worksheet
Dim Tue As Worksheet
Dim Wed As Worksheet
Dim Thur As Worksheet
Dim Fri As Worksheet
Dim Sat As Worksheet

''Sheet Names
Set Mon = Sheets("Monday prices")
Set Tue = Sheets("Tuesday prices")
Set Wed = Sheets("Wednesday prices")
Set Thur = Sheets("Thursday price")
Set Fri = Sheets("Friday price")
Set Sat = Sheets("Saturday price")

''Dates
todayDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
sheetDate = "Sheet_Date"


''*************************
''Change dates on sheets
''*************************
Mon.Range(sheetDate) = todayDate
Tue.Range(sheetDate) = DateAdd("d", 1, todayDate)
Wed.Range(sheetDate) = DateAdd("d", 2, todayDate)
Thur.Range(sheetDate) = DateAdd("d", 3, todayDate)
Fri.Range(sheetDate) = DateAdd("d", 4, todayDate)
Sat.Range(sheetDate) = DateAdd("d", 5, todayDate)


''*************************
''Transfer prices from Saturday sheet to Monday sheet
''*************************
Sat.Range("E11:E487").Copy Mon.Range("E11:E487")
Sat.Range("G209:G356").Copy Mon.Range("G209:G356")


''*************************
''Clear other sheets
''*************************
''Clear Prices
Tue.Range("E11:E487").ClearContents
Wed.Range("E11:E487").ClearContents
Thur.Range("E11:E487").ClearContents
Fri.Range("E11:E487").ClearContents
Sat.Range("E11:E487").ClearContents

''Clear Discounts
Tue.Range("G209:G356").ClearContents
Wed.Range("G209:G356").ClearContents
Thur.Range("G209:G356").ClearContents
Fri.Range("G209:G356").ClearContents
Sat.Range("G209:G356").ClearContents
```

End Sub